# On creating div element give ordered class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

By clicking Create I want to give continuing class name: For example now if you click Create button, it should create the following `<div class="div_3">Div 3</div>`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div_1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div_2">Div 2</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Create"/>
```

Here is JS

```
function add(){
    $("#container").append("<div>Div 3</div>")
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gmr5j8z/

Comment: Why would you want this? The whole point of classes is that they group elements together. If you want to uniquely identify them use an `id`, however even that is not a great idea. The best pattern to use is to group elements by class and then traverse them using their index.

Comment: I should give diffrent class names, because I will use them for diffrent actions, that's why I don't give the same ID

Comment: @hasratyan@: You will usually be better off with a single handler and data-driving the different actions (e.g. from `data-` attributes). You will need to show more of the intended code first though to give a good example.

Comment: i was wondering if you are just going to name them in order why not just use "nth-child" to find the child you need and not name them in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to count the existing elements (and add 1):

```
$("#container").append("<div>Div " + ($("#container div").length+1) + "</div>");
```

**Simple JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5gmr5j8z/2/

You need to apply the same to the class, but this gets a little messy, so neater version below.

You are also better off using jQuery to connect events. Inline event handlers do not have the power of jQuery handlers (and separate event registration from the event handler for no good reason):

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var count = $("#container div").length + 1;
    var $div = $("<div>", {
        class: "div_" + count,
        text: "Div " + count
    });
    $("#container").append($div);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5gmr5j8z/3/

*There are usually neater ways to do this sort of thing, but you need to explain the overall aim first*

Comment: And what about class name?

Comment: @hasratyan: Was busy creating a better example... see second one :)